# How to store a temp_value in a for loop to be checked next iteration of the same for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, indexing

I have a script that creates bins. Next i loop over these bins and calculate some values. When i calculate in the first iteration of the loop i want to store a temp value which i can check within the same loop in the next iteration. Then after checking i want to fill the temp_value with the current value of the loops iteration.

```
previous_temp=None
loop_over = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10]

for i in loop_over:
    print(i)
    previous_temp = i
    if previous_temp == i:
        print("previous bin contains same value")
    if previous_temp != i:
        print("previous bin is different then other value")
```

This is my best attempt so far. I know i am comparing the same thing al over again, but i simply cant get my hands around this issue. Hope that someone of you people can give me some hints or solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using another list to store these values. You can index it like this

```
loop_over = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10]
previous_temp=[None]*len(loop_over)

for index, val in enumerate(loop_over):
    print(index, val)
    # TODO - check for edge case
    if previous_temp[i-1] == i:
        print("previous bin contains same value")
    else:
        print("previous bin is different then other value")
```